# Fabric8 Docker Maven Plugin: How to tag just one image? docker:tag

Tags: docker, maven, fabric8, docker-maven-plugin, docker-tag

When I use `docker:tag` of Fabric.io's docker-maven-plugin,
it tags all my images:

```
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.40.2:tag (tag-latest) @ tracker-service-app ---
[INFO] DOCKER> Tagging image dacadoo/db-with-data:latest successful!
[INFO] DOCKER> Tagging image dacadoo/tracker-service-app:latest successful!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.40.2:tag (tag-v-g) @ tracker-service-app ---
[INFO] DOCKER> Tagging image dacadoo/db-with-data:1.0-SNAPSHOT-fc5f529 successful!
[INFO] DOCKER> Tagging image dacadoo/tracker-service-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT-fc5f529 successful!
```

Is there a way to tag just one?
[The documentation](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:tag) doesn't mention any such option...

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer - I need to use `docker.filter`, which is a bit tricky as I am tagging from executions bound to lifecycle phases. But doable.

https://dmp.fabric8.io/#global-configuration